# Allocation of 86973087744 exceeds 10% of system memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[image]I am using SRGAN for super-resolution if images from 64x64 to 1024x1024 image. The network is very deep (it has 16 residual blocks). If I use the code for super-resolution from 64x64 to 256x256, everything is fine. But for 16x upsampling, I start getting the memory error. I am using Nvidia GeForce GTC 1080Ti. On System monitor, I see the memory and swap going up to the maximum values, and after some time the code crashes. I have also installed Tensorflow GPU version. Why is the code using CPU memory instead of GPU memory?

Comment: System RAM will always be used to a degree, I am not sure what exactly you are asking.

Comment: In my case, if I check the GPU memory using nvidia-smi, I dont see it is getting used 100%. But, my CPU memory gets used 100%. Should the Tensorflow also not use GPU memory?

Comment: Using GPU memory does not mean it has to use it to 100%.

Comment: In my case, I don't see any GPU memory getting used by Tensorflow. I see CPU memory going up but not GPU memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could try before starting the session :

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.7)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

Since it limits the usage of GPU memory I think you will not have memory crashes. However, keep in mind that with limited usage of GPU memory, the process will be longer. Furthermore `os.environ` would makes you sure that you are in the CUDA. However `="0"` part could be changed from system to system. You can also try `=""` as well.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But it did not help. I again see the same behavior with CPU memory. It becomes maximum and after some time the code crashes. I have added the screenshot of the system monitor in the post. Thank you.